# How to Copy Data one table to another table using sql server 2005 query?

Tags: sql-server-2005

i want to Copy data one table to another table

```
my table out put like this


EnrollNo     CheckIn    CheckOut      DiffTime
92            NULL        NULL        NULL
3032        09:40:00    18:31:00    08:51:00
4011        18:30:00    18:38:00    00:08:00
4019        18:32:00    18:32:00    00:00:00
438         10:00:00    18:32:00    08:32:00
```

Comment: Both table structure and schema same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To insert into an existing table

```
INSERT INTO Destination
            (EnrollNo,
             CheckIn,
             CheckOut,
             DiffTime)
SELECT EnrollNo,
       CheckIn,
       CheckOut,
       DiffTime
FROM   Source
```

Or to create a new table

```
SELECT EnrollNo,
       CheckIn,
       CheckOut,
       DiffTime
INTO NewTable
FROM   Source
```

Comment: @martin Smith this is an awesome answer +1 for this,Well if you want to insert new row then insert command like the way you said should be applied but if you want to copy from one table and update into another table,then how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much. both the option works.
create table newtable as select * from source;

Step1:  select * from FT_customer;
TC_CNO TC_NAMETC_ADDRESS      TC_STATE       TC_ZIP TC_PHONE   TC_REMARKS

---

```
 1 TRUE WHEEL   55O HUSK    ER 58702 555-4545   NONE
 2 BIKE SPEC    CPT SHRIV   EL 45678 555-1234   NONE
 3 LE SHOPPE    POMETOWN    KS 54678 555-1234   NONE
 4 AAA BIKE     10 OLDTOWN  NE 56784 555-1234   NONE
 5 JACKS BIKE   24 EGLIN    FL 34567 555-2314   NONE
```

Step2: create table a as select * from ft_customer;
select * from a;

TC_CNO TC_NAMETC_ADDRESS      TC_STATE       TC_ZIP TC_PHONE   TC_REMARKS

---

```
 1 TRUE WHEEL   55O HUSK    ER 58702 555-4545   NONE
 2 BIKE SPEC    CPT SHRIV   EL 45678 555-1234   NONE
 3 LE SHOPPE    POMETOWN    KS 54678 555-1234   NONE
 4 AAA BIKE     10 OLDTOWN  NE 56784 555-1234   NONE
 5 JACKS BIKE   24 EGLIN    FL 34567 555-2314   NONE
```

Priya

abcpune.com